# OSX monterey -> ld: library not found for -lintl

Tags: python, django, macos, pip

When `pipenv install uwsgi`

This error comes, `ld: library not found for -lintl`

I guess it requires X-code library ?

I tried this as well

```
$xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

However it is already installed.

How can I solve this?

---

I checked the verbose log with

`pipenv install uwsgi -v`

```
  *** uWSGI linking ***
  clang -o /Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/aicomposer-Enqobsfe/bin/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/regexp.o core/routing.o core/yaml.o core/json.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -lz -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/lib -lpcre -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jansson/2.14/lib -ljansson -lexpat -lintl -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.9.10/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin/libpython3.9.a
  ld: library not found for -lintl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  *** error linking uWSGI ***
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for uwsgi did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/aicomposer-Enqobsfe/bin/python -u -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize
  
  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )
      sys.exit(1)
  
  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__
  
  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"
  
  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'/private/var/folders/bg/d6c8dpss5gg4qpnyy5y640rr0000gn/T/pip-install-o3nusm15/uwsgi_bf359134a4234fd890ca6dc16550331a/setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' install --record /private/var/folders/bg/d6c8dpss5gg4qpnyy5y640rr0000gn/T/pip-record-30vh_20n/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/aicomposer-Enqobsfe/include/site/python3.9/uwsgi
  cwd: /private/var/folders/bg/d6c8dpss5gg4qpnyy5y640rr0000gn/T/pip-install-o3nusm15/uwsgi_bf359134a4234fd890ca6dc16550331a/
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> uwsgi

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Using pip 22.0.4 from /Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/aicomposer-Enqobsfe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
Collecting uwsgi
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.20.tar.gz (804 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Building wheel for uwsgi (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for uwsgi (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi: started
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi: finished with status 'error'
```

Answer (score 0):

This https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1364 post suggests to do:

```
brew update
brew unlink libxml2
brew uninstall libxml2

brew install --with-python libxml2
brew link libxml2 --force
```

(take care to have those one outside of any virtualenv it is mentioned)
and then

```
pip install uwsgi
```

Comment: Thank you , but brew install doesn't have `Error: invalid option: --with-python`